# iptables: write UDPv4: Operation not permitted (code=1)

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, iptables

I am trying to set up a stateful firewall using iptables. It is for use on my desktop machine.

Below are the contents of my firewall script:

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables-save > /home/username/iptables.save

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j DROP --ctstate INVALID
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP -m tcp -m conntrack -s a.b.c.d -i eth0 --sport 1275 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p UDP -m tcp -m conntrack -d a.b.c.d -o eth0 --dport 1275 -j ACCEPT --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -o tun0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack -i tun0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT  --ctstate ESTABLISHED
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

After I am connected to the VPN server whose IP address is a.b.c.d using port 1275 and UDP protocol, I launch the above firewall. (I don't use the NetworkManager)

Immediately an error message pops up, stating

```
write UDPv4: Operation not permitted (code=1)
```

What has happened?

How do I fix the issue?

P.S.: Please feel free to improve on my iptables rules.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a iptables frontend, like `shorewall` or `ufw` just to mention two, as it will make it easier for you to get a proper firewall up and running instead of hacking one with `iptables` and `ip6tables`. And why `-p udp` and `-m tcp` in same rule?

Comment: @Anders: Thanks for pointing out my mistake of mixing `-p udp` and `-m tcp` in the same rules. Even after correcting them to `-p udp` and `-m udp`, I still encounter the same error message.

Comment: @Anders If I choose to install `shorewall`, from where should I download it? From the repos or Shorewall's official site?

Comment: Always from repos, never from source, as you then have to manage bug and security fixes yourself.  You do not want that.  But documentations from web site is good, use that.
Example configurations can be copied from `/usr/share/docs/shorewall` directory (or some of the other with similar name in `/usr/share/docs/`).